# Why do QM books point out that $S^2$ commutes with $S_x$, $S_y$, and $S_z$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, representation-theory, linear-algebra

The spin angular momentum magnitude squared operator:

$$S^2=S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2=\frac{3\hbar^2}{4}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Obviously $S^2$ commutes with everything, so why do QM books
point out that it commutes with $S_x$, $S_y$, and $S_z$?

Since *any* vector is an eigenvector of $S^2$, it seems like a trivial property.

Comment: Related buzzwords for looking into this concept more: [Casimir invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element), Representation theory

Comment: @SillyGoose Consider to expand this out as an answer.

Comment: It is also a special case of something more general.  It is less trivial that $\vec{J}{}^{2}$ commutes with $J_{x}$, $J_{y}$, and $J_{z}$ if the angular momentum is not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I always thought it was to emphasise that $S_i$ and $S^2$ can be simultaneously measured.

Comment: Hint: much less trivial if the representation is reducible.

Comment: Have you ever worked out explicitly the "addition" of a spin 1/2 to a spin 1 particle/state?

Answer (score 2):

Your QM book stresses these facts because it means that this operator is something called the ["Casimir invariant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element#Case_of_so(3)), which must be proportional to the identity operator and commute with all generators.

One important result is that, because the total angular momentum commutes with the components of angular momentum, the [hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom) solutions involve both the total angular momentum quantum number $\ell$ and the $z$-component's quantum number $m$.

The other important result is that the Casimir invariant essentially defines the different representations of a Lie group (and really, its corresponding Lie *algebra*) in terms of their "spin" and constrains their allowed quantum numbers.

In this case, the Lie group corresponds to the group of rotations of 3d space SO(3). The fundamental representation of 3d rotations correspond to $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrices with unit determinant. This representation is irreducible (known as an irrep). But we can pick other irreps as well with different dimension. It turns out that the representations of the separate Lie group SU(2) are "projective" representations of SO(3), meaning that they have the same algebraic properties (i.e., commutation relations) up to a complex phase. Moreover, the elements of these groups are continuously parametrized in terms of exponentials of the "generators" of the corresponding Lie *algebras*, which are $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, respectively. It happens that these two Lie algebras are equivalent, and their three nontrivial generators $J_\nu$ satisfy $[J_a,J_b] = 2 i \epsilon_{abc} J^c$. Like the spin operators you've written above, or angular momentum operators when solving, e.g., the [hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom).

As an aside, you can think of SU(2) as being a projective representation of actual rotations, or as coming from the representations of the Lorentz group SO(3,1), which includes rotations of 3d space and Lorentz boosts on 4d spacetime. The representations of SO(3,1) are related to those of SU(2)$\times$SU(2). One of these SU(2)s corresponds to intrinsic spin and the other to matter vs. antimatter!

Anyway, the fact that the square of the total angular momentum or spin operator ($L^2$ or $S^2$) commutes with all three generators of the algebra tells us that the (irreducible) representations are characterized by some quantum number $\ell$ (or $s$), corresponding to total angular momentum. As you wrote, we have that $L^2 = \ell (\ell+1) \mathbb{1}$ (in civilized units where $\hbar = 1$). Importantly, *there is a direct correspondence between the dimension of the representation and the "spin"*, i.e., when the generator $S_i$  written as a $d \times d$ matrix, we find that $s = (d-1)/2$ (likewise for $L_i$ and $\ell$).

We can then define raising and lowering (or "ladder") operators, from which we can work out the set of states that form the Hilbert space that the three generators (and Casimir invariant) act on. Importantly, *we always assign a second quantum number $m$ to a particular axis of the angular momentum (or spin) vector*.  Because $L^2$ ($S^2$) commutes with all of the generators, we get another quantum number to label states. But since the three generators do not commute, we only get one quantum number, which we usually denote $m$ and assign to the $z$ component of angular momentum $L_z$, or the $z$ component of spin $S_z$. This is done in solving, e.g., the [hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom), e.g., and it can also be applied to spin systems.

I think it's good that your textbook points this out because my perspective is that abstract algebra (groups and representations, Lie groups and algrebras, operator algebras and $C^*$-algebras, etc.) provide the most elegant description of quantum mechanics. But there are many aspects of quantum mechanics for which this business about Casimir invariants is not needed.

Comment: To be pedantic, what is meant by "equivalently $\mathfrak{su}(2)$" is not a trivial statement. Since (pure) quantum states are rays, we are allowed to consider *projective representations* of the rotation group $SO(3)$. By Bargmann's theorem and other mathematics, this is equivalent to finding normal representations of the universal cover of $SO(3)$, which is isomorphic to $SU(2)$, which is equivalent to finding normal representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. This is why all these quantum texts associate representations of $SU(2)$ and its Lie algebra with spin, even though naively it'd be SO(3).

Comment: What you write is true for the Lie groups, but I think what I wrote is true for the Lie algebras? Basically, SU(2) irreps are projective representations of SO(3), but SU(2) and SO(3) have the *same* Lie *algebra*. Right?

Comment: You are right that they have isomorphic Lie algebras. I mean to say that it is nontrivial to justify why looking for normal representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ gives us all of the projective representations of $SO(3)$.

Comment: Ohh I see, and that's a worthwhile comment! I usually think of rotations as just SO(3) and then think of SU(2) spin as coming from irreps of the orthochronus Lorentz group SO(3,1)$_+$ instead. I'll try to clarify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 x 2 spin matrices are for the (fundamental) spinor representation: two component spinors.

All two component spinors have a spin quantum number $s=\frac 1 2$, and a fixed angular momentum:

$$ S = \sqrt{s(s+1)}\hbar = \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \hbar $$

which is the square-root of the eigenvalue of $S^2$.

What that means is that all spinors have fixed spin angular momentum, regardless of their orientation.

That it commutes with the spin projection operator on any axis (not just $x, y, z$) means that you can simultaneously know $S$ and $S_i$ where $i$ is some axis. We usually chose $i=z$, for reasons, so you can have eigenstates with quantum numbers $(s, s_z)$ with:
$$ S =  \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 \hbar $$
$$ S_z = \frac 1 2 \hbar $$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\ket[1]{|{#1}\rangle}\newcommand\up{\uparrow}\newcommand\down{\downarrow}$To expound on one of the comments: $S^2$ is not always so simple, as a matrix. For a system with a *fixed* spin, yes, $S^2$ is just some multiple of the identity. But some systems can have varying (total) spin, e.g. two electrons considered together ($2\cdot2=4$ orthogonal states) can have total spin 0 (one state) or total spin 1 (three states). In the $\ket{\up\up},\ket{\up\down},\ket{\down\up},\ket{\down\down}$ basis, $S^2,S_z$ are now $$S^2=\hbar^2\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix},S_z=\hbar\begin{pmatrix}1&&&\\&0&&\\&&0&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ These still commute, though certainly $S^2$ doesn't commute with everything (the 2 non-obvious eigenvectors of $S^2$ are $\ket{0,0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\ket{\up\down}-\ket{\down\up}]$ of eigenvalue $0$ and $\ket{1,0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\ket{\up\down}+\ket{\down\up}]$ of eigenvalue $2\hbar^2$).

The proof that a total angular momentum operator $J^2=J_x^2+J_y^2+J_z^2$ commutes with all the component operators $J_x,J_y,J_z$ depends only on the given definition of $J^2$ and the commutation relations among the $J_i$ (which we can interpret as specifying their nature as angular momentum operators). Thus the proof works *generally* for all kinds of angular momentum (spin, orbital, sums thereof) in all kinds of systems that may not be as simple as your special case.